# How to generate random numbers with each random number having a difference of at least x with all other elements?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I know this goes against the definition of random numbers, but still I require this for my project.
For instance, I want to generate an array with 5 random elements in `range(0, 200)`.

Now, I want each of the elements to have a difference of at least 15 between them.
So the random array should look something like this:

```
[15, 45, 99, 132, 199]
```

I can generate random numbers using numpy:

```
np.random.uniform(low=0, high=200, size=5)
```

However, I am not able to keep a consistent difference of at least 15.

Comment: If efficiency is not a concern, you could use a while loop, that generates the value until it fits your requirement

Comment: Get a random between 0 and 200-15, and then just add 15 to that value... If it's stupid, but it works...

Comment: Do you need any particular distribution? Something like a Poisson process would work (you start with 0, then add a random number between 15 and X to get the next one, etc.). `X` can be modified at each step to make sure you don't go over 200 before you get the required number of elements.

Comment: You show only integers in the question.  Is that what you want, or can the random values be floating point (e.g. [1.343, 29.81, 74.4, 121.83, 189.9])?

Comment: The only violation of randomness is in the sense that you can't simply choose each number at random from the range 0 to 200 without replacement, because that could violate the spacing condition. However, it *is* perfectly sound to discuss choosing a particular tuple at random from the set of tuples that *do* satisfy the spacing. You just have to be specific about how you state the problem.

Comment: By the way, there are 498,187,404 such 5-tuples to choose from. Picking one at random isn't too hard; the hard part is doing it in such a way that any *one* of them is equally likely to be chosen.

Comment: Answering my own question: You wrote "I can generate random numbers using numpy: np.random.uniform(low=0, high=200, size=5)", and that function returns floating point samples from the uniform distribution, so apparently you don't want just integer samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be nice if the question showed more effort towards solving the problem (i.e. from the [Stack Overflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"), but sometimes a question triggers an itch you just have to scratch...

Here's one way you could do it, written as the function `random_spaced`:

```
import numpy as np


def random_spaced(low, high, delta, n, size=None):
    """
    Choose n random values between low and high, with minimum spacing delta.

    If size is None, one sample is returned.
    Set size=m (an integer) to return m samples.

    The values in each sample returned by random_spaced are in increasing
    order.
    """
    empty_space = high - low - (n-1)*delta
    if empty_space < 0:
        raise ValueError("not possible")

    if size is None:
        u = np.random.rand(n)
    else:
        u = np.random.rand(size, n)
    x = empty_space * np.sort(u, axis=-1)
    return low + x + delta * np.arange(n)
```

For example,

```
In [27]: random_spaced(0, 200, 15, 5)
Out[27]: array([ 30.3524969 ,  97.4773284 , 140.38221631, 161.9276264 , 189.3404236 ])

In [28]: random_spaced(0, 200, 15, 5)
Out[28]: array([ 81.01616136, 103.11710522, 118.98018499, 141.68196775, 169.02965952])
```

The `size` argument lets you generate more than one sample at a time:

```
In [29]: random_spaced(0, 200, 15, 5, size=3)
Out[29]: 
array([[ 52.62401348,  80.04494534,  96.21983265, 138.68552066, 178.14784825],
       [  7.57714106,  33.05818556,  62.59831316,  81.86507168, 180.30946733],
       [ 24.16367913,  40.37480075,  86.71321297, 148.24263974, 195.89405713]])
```

This code generates a histogram for each component using 100000 samples, and plots the corresponding theoretical marginal PDFs of each component:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import beta

low = 0
high = 200
delta = 15 
n = 5
s = random_spaced(low, high, delta, n, size=100000)

for k in range(s.shape[1]):
    plt.hist(s[:, k], bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.25)
plt.title("Normalized marginal histograms and marginal PDFs")
plt.grid(alpha=0.2)

# Plot the PDFs of the marginal distributions of each component.
# These are beta distributions.
for k in range(n):
    left = low + k*delta
    right = high - (n - k - 1)*delta
    xx = np.linspace(left, right, 400)
    yy = beta.pdf(xx, k + 1, n - k, loc=left, scale=right - left)
    plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k--', linewidth=1, alpha=0.25)
    if n > 1:
        # Mark the mode with a dot.
        mode0 = k/(n-1)
        mode = (right-left)*mode0 + left
        plt.plot(mode, beta.pdf(mode, k + 1, n - k, loc=left, scale=right - left),
                 'k.', alpha=0.25)

plt.show()
```

Here's the plot that it generates:

[image: plot]

As can be seen in the plot, the marginal distributions are [beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  The modes of the marginal distributions correspond to the positions of `n` evenly spaced points on the interval `[low, high]`.

By fiddling with how `u` is generated in `random_spaced`, distributions with different marginals can be generated (an old version of this answer had an example), but the distribution that `random_spaced` currently generates seems to be a natural choice.  As mentioned above, the modes of the marginals occur in "meaningful" positions. Moreover, in the trivial case where `n` is 1, the distribution simplifies to the uniform distribution on [`low`, `high`].

Comment: Will be sure to add attempted solutions next time in the question asked. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about trial-and-error?  e.g. throw some random numbers, sort, compute differences... and if too small repeat?

```
import random as r

def spreadRandom(theRange, howMany, minSpacing):
    while True:
        candidate = sorted([r.randint(*theRange) for _ in range(howMany)])
        minDiff = min([ candidate[i+1]-candidate[i] for i, _ in enumerate(candidate[:-1])])
        if minDiff >= minSpacing:
            return candidate

spreadRandom([0,200], 5, 15)
```

You're not guaranteed to ever get an answer, but you're not biasing your numbers at all as you might be by enforcing ranges based on neighboring numbers.

Comment: I tried to do something similar, but for this project, having something not totally random was acceptable. Again, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try shuffling the numbers 0-200:

```
import random
numbers = list(range(200))
random.shuffle(numbers)
distant_numbers = [numbers[0]]
for number in numbers:
    if any(abs(number - x) < 15 for x in distant_numbers):
        continue
    distant_numbers.append(number)
    if len(distant_numbers) >= 5: break
```

Edit:

Here's a solution that uses `z3` for massive overkill:

```
def spaced_randoms(n, d, R, first=None):
    solver = z3.SolverFor("QF_FD")
    numbers = [z3.Int("x{}".format(x)) for x in range(n)]
    for number in numbers:
        solver.add(number >= 0)
        solver.add(number <= R)
    for ii in range(n):
        for jj in range(ii+1,n):
            solver.add(z3.Or(numbers[ii] - numbers[jj] > d, numbers[ii] - numbers[jj] < -d))
    if first is not None:
        solver.add(numbers[0] == first)
    result = solver.check()
    if str(result) != "sat":
        raise Exception("Unsatisfiable")
    model = solver.model()
    return [model.get_interp(number) for number in numbers]
```

Call it like this for a random result:

```
import random
spaced_randoms(n, d, R, random.randint(0,R))
```

Comment: For `n = 5`, `d = 15`, and `R = 200` (I made up the parameter names; it should be clear what they represent), this should guarantee a solution, although for general `n`, `d`, and `R`, it might fail to find a solution if the solution space is too small. (As an extreme example, imagine you had to find 5 numbers separated by 15 between 0 and 75. The only solution is 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, so if you started with any number but one of these 5, the loop would terminate before `distant_numbers` was long enough.)

Comment: @chepner Certainly, although the problem is far worse with the "keep drawing random numbers until satisfied" solutions.  I'm going to stick in an edit that uses Z3 for massive overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code might help for your specific needs:

```
import random
import numpy as np
five_list = np.asarray([])
end = False
number = random.randint(0,200)
five_list = np.append(five_list,number)
while True:
    new_number = random.randint(0,200)
    if all(np.absolute(np.subtract(five_list, new_number)) >= 15):
        five_list = np.append(five_list,new_number)
    if np.size(five_list) == 5:
        break
print(np.sort(five_list))
```

Comment: You don't need both the `end` variable and `break`; one or the other will terminate the loop (assuming it terminates; it should for a large enough solution space, but in general it may not).

Comment: @chepner I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with "brute force":

```
l= [ i for i in range(201) ]
rslt= []
for i in range(5): 
    n=random.choice(l) 
    rslt.append(n) 
    l=[ k for k in l if abs(k-n)>=15 ]
    #if not l:
    #   break
```

Or smartly:

```
sgmnts= [(0,200)]
diff= 15
rslt= []

for i in range(5):

    start,stop= sgmnts.pop( random.choice(range(len(sgmnts))) )
    n= random.choice(range(start,stop+1))
    rslt.append(n)
    if n-diff > start:
        sgmnts.append( (start,n-diff) )
    if n+diff < stop:
        sgmnts.append( (n+diff,stop) )
    if not sgmnts:
        break
```

"sgmnts" stores the suitable ranges. We select a range randomly, too, by index.

Answer (score -1):

This will generate 5 random values between 200 with a step of 5

```
import random

array = []

randomRange = 200
arrayRange = 5
valueStep = 15

for loop in range(arrayRange):
    randomMaxValue = randomRange - valueStep * (arrayRange - loop) # First loop will the first randomMaxValue be 125 next will be 140, 155, 170, 185, 200
    if not array: # Checks if the array is empty
        array.append(random.randint(0, randomMaxValue)) # Appends a value between 0 and 125 (First will be 125 because 200 - 15 * 5)
    else:
        array.append(random.randint(array[-1] + 15, randomMaxValue)) # Appends the 4 next values

print(array)
```

Comment: I was thinking of this as well, but it appears to be biased against lower numbers. While testing, I almost always get 4 numbers between 100 and 200, and rarely get even 2 numbers less than 100, let alone more than 2.

Comment: There could be a possibility of increasing the chances of lower numbers, but then it won't be true random.

Comment: @ZuperZee The weighted probability of a result (or range of results) doesn't necessarily decide whether it's "true random". If I have a bag with 9999 red marbles and 1 blue marble, the colour of the marble I pull out is still random.

Comment: On a big project you shouldn't have something that can take _a long_ time to get a value, like you would when you loop through to find something that doesn't go over the max set value.